# Find a surface with given principal curvatures.

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to find a surface with principal curvatures at a point $k_1=2$, $k_2=-1$. Any idea how to find this?

Comment: You have to give an example of a surface that in some point the principal curvatures take that values, is that all?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: Take a hyperbolic paraboloid with saddle at the point. Play with the coefficients (semiaxes) to get the desired curvatures

Comment: @Dog_69 yes. this is a a past exam question so i ask if there is any method to answer these type of questions for any given principal curvatures

Comment: @Giannis Yes, there is. You should have seen the classification of the points according the principal curvatures and typical examples of surfaces for each case. In this case, you have $k_1>0$ and $k_2<0$ so at least you should be able to say that it is a hyperbolic point. What surface do you know that has hyperbolic points? Then, give the equation that describes the surface with those particular values may be rather more difficult. But still, if you have studied the typical surfaces, you should be able to reproduce GReyes reasoning.